# Как пересоздать GUID ветку реестра при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите каким образом оставить имя ветки реестра и перезаписать в нее значения?

Или удалять старую ветку реестра, чтобы добавлялась сгенерированная через GUID

Код который генерирует GUID в `textBox1` и добавляет текст через `textBox2`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\001", true).CreateSubKey(textBox1.Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
    key.SetValue("text", textBox2.Text, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default.SaveGUID))
    {
        Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\001", true).DeleteSubKey(Properties.Settings.Default.SaveGUID, false);
    }

    Properties.Settings.Default.SaveGUID = textBox1.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.SaveTEXT = textBox2.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: Добавил рабочий код, если кто-то увидит в нем, что-то лишнее, дайте знать.

Comment: В конечном итоге вы что хотите сделать то, изменить значение конкретного ключа  в узле реестра?

Comment: Да, но сложность в том, что GUID генерируется, и нельзя взять статическое имя раздела, так как генерируются новые рандомные значения...

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите взять имя узла, который был создан ранее, и переписать в нем значение. Но останавливает вас то, что имя представлено в виде `Guid` и вы его не знаете. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, все верно. Не могу сообразить, как оставить старый GUID и изменить значение конкретного ключа в этом узле реестра. Потому как при нажатии на кнопку, происходит генерация GUID и все стирается...

Comment: А почему не сохранить старый `Guid` перед тем как создавать узел?

Comment: Спасибо за мысль, получилось с двумя `if`, если в `...SaveGUID`  пусто, то разрешено генерировать, если `...SaveGUID` содержит значение, то открываем узел через `OpenSubKey` и берем значение в `...SaveGUID`.